# Average of DATE field in Teradata

Tags: sql, date, teradata

I have a column of data in [DATE] format. It is a record of the first time an order was purchased. I am attempting to query the average date in this column. Meaning, I want to know what the average "first purchase" is.

```
Purchase_dt
01-01-2014
02-01-2014
03-05-2014
```

I need something to show what the average purchase_dt is.

Cheers

Comment: The "average of a date" does not make any sense. What output do you expect from your sample data?

Comment: How about pick an arbitrary start date, calculate the number of days from the start date to each of the dates for your column, then average that, and convert it back into a date?

Comment: @TrippKinetics: what difference would that make? Asking for the average of "Monday", "Wednesday" and "Friday" does not make sense.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - "Mean" of the dates??? I have over 6million values in that column. I just want to know what the numerical middle is for all the dates. So, hypothetically, if there are 365 values in the column. One for each day of 2013. I would know that the "average" is ~6-30-13

Comment: Still doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - if it were a smaller data set it would be easier to accomplish. let's say i want to spool out all 6million rows ordered from oldest to newest and then just go to the 3millionth row and find what date falls in the middle of all dates. how do i do that?

Comment: @SQLAccessRookie That would give you the MEDIAN date, not the MEAN date.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The average of "Monday", "Wednesday" and "Friday" could be calculated as:  Take Monday as 0.  Therefore Wednesday is 2, Friday is 4.  0+2+4=6.  6/3=2.  Therefore the average is Wednesday.  Seems fairly straightforward to me.

Comment: That's simply `min(date) + (max(date) - min(date) / 2)`

Comment: Not necessarily.  What if you're taking the average of Monday, Monday, Monday, Monday, Wednesday, Friday?  Then the answer is: 0+0+0+0+2+4=6, 6/6=1.  Therefore the average is Tuesday.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a AVG on a DATE column, in fact it's using the same algorithm Tripp Kinetics mentioned. But it's probably using an INT as intermediate result, which soon results in a "*numeric overflow*"

For a larger number of rows you'll need to do the calculation manually like:

DATE '1900-01-01' + CAST(AVG(CAST(trans_date-DATE '1900-01-01'AS BIGINT)) AS INT)